# Jquery live with select method problem in internet explorer

Tags: select, focus, live, jquery

I want to use jquery live() to automatically select the text in a text box but it doesn't seem to work in internet explorer 8. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $('input.textInput')
    .live('focus',
        function(e){
            $(this).select();
            // alert(1) // if i uncomment this it works
        });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="textInput" value="0,00" />
</body>
</html>
```

If, however, i uncomment the alert(1) statement it does work. Any ideas what the problem is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strange, it also works if you don't use the live event:
http://jsfiddle.net/JKVXU/1/

Comment: True... maybe it's a bug? I've tried with varying versions of jQuery with the same result.

Comment: It's definitely a jQuery bug, not an IE bug (for a change ;-))

Comment: Thanks for your help Capsule. I'll implement a work around for now and try to log a ticket with the jQuery guys

Comment: Logged a ticket. This is the work around for now if anybody runs into the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/timmywil/m9Pyu/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('input.textInput').live("focus",function(e){
    $(this).focus(function () {
        $(this).select();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JKVXU/23/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `val()` to get the text box vlaue instead?

Comment: some thing like:
$(this).val($(this).val()+'changed');
works without the alert. But not the select().
Strange.

Comment: Are you sure `select()` is the right thing to use? looking at the jquery documentation, select either allows you to register an event to respond to the user selecting text, or if you call without any parameters it will fire the event. it does not seem to mention that it causes the text to be actually selected, just respond or fire an event.

Answer (score -1):

I think the browser doesn't like the integer value on the alert.

try this:  alert('1');

Comment: there's no problem with the alert. that works just fine, and if anything fixes the problem (if only my users didn't mind an alert everytime the click the text field ;). The problem is that without the alert the select doesn't run. Thanks tho'.